# App Store - ratings and reviews - table view or collection view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

Does anyone know what Apple is using for the "Ratings and Reviews" screen of the AppStore app? Is it a UITableView or a UICollectionView or is it something else?

Here is the screen I am talking about:
[image]

I have an app where I am wanting to implement a similar view. Perhaps I do not need the top part where it shows the histogram (though it would still be nice to be able to add something similar maybe), but mostly I am focused on just being able to display a list of reviews, where each review has the user information, a rating, some other data about the product, and then the review itself. The review should be able to be expanded, just like the one in the AppStore.

So I am just trying to figure out which way is the best for implementing something like this. I would guess it could be done either in a table view or a collection view, but which is the best way for maintainability, performance, features, the ability to resize cells, ..., to implement this? I was just curious how Apple is doing it.

Thank you.

Comment: Both are fine and are pretty much the same in term of performance, but you can get much more customization with collection views.

Comment: @aheze Thank you so much for your comment. I am considering possibly a collection view, but I am just a bit hesitant because I have to support at a minimum iOS 13, and I have read some really nice features for supporting lists in collection views came out in iOS 14, but not iOS 13. So that is my only concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran across this video yesterday talking about the collection view layouts of the App Store. You should check it out. He also put a git-hub repo of the code.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SR7DtcT61tA

In your case you could use collection view or table view or any combination of the two.